# Finding all occurrences of certain words from user text input using regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I want to accept user input via a text field and count the matches against a defined list of words (can be stored anywhere). This led me to `String#scan` and regexes. I'm wondering whether it is the best to convert the defined list of words into a new regex (in which case I need to figure out how to define the regex), and pass it to `scan` on the input text. I could then edit the defined list of words without affecting the regex method rather than manually building the regex based on the current word list.

Is this a good way to tackle this problem? Is there a better solution? Can I do this without regex?

Comment: Note that `String.scan` does not mean what you intended. You mean `String#scan`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `String#split` and `Array#count?`.

Count of search terms found:

```
story        = 'A long foo ago, in a bar baz, baz away...'
search_terms = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
search_terms.count { |search_term| story.split(/\W+/).include? search_term }
  # => 3
```

Count of words which are one of the search terms:

```
story        = 'A long foo ago, in a bar baz, baz away...'
search_terms = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
story.split(/\W+/).count { |word| search_terms.include? word }
  # => 4
```

Comment: The OP wants to count. The title may be a bit misleading, but "finding **all** occurrences" cannot not mean "finding if there is **any** occurrence".

Comment: Notice that `'A long fime ago, in a baraxy baz, baz away...'.split(/ |\b/)` gives an element like `","` or `"..."`.

Comment: @sawa, agree, but is that a problem. Or are you just saying that my choice of variable name (`word`) is bad?

Comment: It works, but perhaps you can improve the regex (I would go with `/\W+/`). I am implicitly assuming that the word list would not include entities like `","` or `"..."`.

Comment: You might also write `search_terms.include? word.downcase`.